# wpf how to binding one TreeView to another TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm trying to bind `TreeView t2` to `TreeView t1` in xaml as below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="620" Width="600">
<Window.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Background="AliceBlue" Text="{Binding Path=Header, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="220"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TreeView x:Name="t1">
        <TreeView.Items>
            <TreeViewItem Header="a"></TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="b"></TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView.Items>
    </TreeView>
    <TreeView x:Name="t2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=t1}"></TreeView>
</StackPanel>
```

I expected `t2` will have the same number of nodes with `t1`. But the result is that, all nodes of `t1` are deleted. `Why`?

I expected result:

[image]

The actual result:

[image]

Comment: I think the issues is you can't bind a treeview to another treeview which are both controls.  But you can bind one treeview item to another treeview item

Comment: The element can have only one parent. The binding will copy `TreeViewItems` one to one to second, replacing parent... I think.

Comment: Why not use the same instance of you ViewModel for both of you controls?

Comment: @Sinatr seems you are right, but  I don't understand why ItemsSource is implemented like this?

Comment: @BurimHajrizaj Yes, I can use ViewModel way, but I just want to understand why I cannot do this.

Answer (score 1):

> I expected `t2` will have the same number of nodes with `t1`. But the result is that, all nodes of `t1` are deleted. Why?

Because an instance of a visual element such as for example a `TreeViewItem` can only appear *once* in the visual tree. An element can have no more than *one* visual parent and in this case the items are removed from the first `TreeView` and added to the second.

So you need to clone each `TreeViewItem` element that you want to be able to display in both `TreeViews`.

Comment: If I binding to a ViewModel object，it will create treeviewitem according to the HierarchicalDataTemplate。Why it is different when binding to t1.Items？

Comment: Because then a TreeViewItem container will be created for each item in the ItemsSource. In your example, you are creating two TreeViewItem elements explicitly. Also note that the DataType for a HierarchicalDataTemplate should not be TreeViewItem but the type of your data object. You should not create any TreeViewItem elements explicity.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

Found the answer from the source code. Seems it's by design (I still don't understand why it's designed like this). If the given item is `TreeViewItem`, then it will be used as the node container in stead of creating a new one.

[ItemsControl.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,dee33c98c4dcf3f2)(line #1323)

```
/// <summary>
    /// Return the element used to display the given item
    /// </summary>
    DependencyObject IGeneratorHost.GetContainerForItem(object item)
    {
        DependencyObject container;

        // use the item directly, if possible (bug 870672)
        if (IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(item))
            container = item as DependencyObject;
        else
            container = GetContainerForItemOverride();

        // the container might have a parent from a previous
        // generation (bug 873118).  If so, clean it up before using it again.
        //
        // Note: This assumes the container is about to be added to a new parent,
        // according to the ItemsControl/Generator/Container pattern.
        // If someone calls the generator and doesn't add the container to
        // a visual parent, unexpected things might happen.
        Visual visual = container as Visual;
        if (visual != null)
        {
            Visual parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visual) as Visual;
            if (parent != null)
            {
                Invariant.Assert(parent is FrameworkElement, SR.Get(SRID.ItemsControl_ParentNotFrameworkElement));
                Panel p = parent as Panel;
                if (p != null && (visual is UIElement))
                {
                    p.Children.RemoveNoVerify((UIElement)visual);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((FrameworkElement)parent).TemplateChild = null;
                }
            }
        }

        return container;
    }
```

And [TreeView](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TreeView.cs,5050528c9202ffc4) (line #400)

```
public class TreeView : ItemsControl {
    ...
    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns true if the item is or should be its own container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item to test.</param>
    /// <returns>true if its type matches the container type.</returns>
    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
        return item is TreeViewItem;
    }
    ....
}
```